# How can I combine fully measured with partially measured outcomes in an IPD (Network) Meta-Analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis, data-imputation, uncertainty

I was asked to help in an Individual-Patient Data (IPD) Network Meta-Analysis (NMA). Outcomes are supposed to measure combined scores of condition 1 and condition 2 (thus: $Score=Score_1 + Score_2$), but also studies only measuring condition 1 will be included. Given Standardized Mean Differences will be considered, I think that taking the observed values of Score 1 for such studies is enough (Scores 2 estimation by Scores 1 would have the same ranking and would be linear combinations of Scores 1, since $\hat{Score_2}=\alpha+\beta Score_1$ ).

My problem is: I need to downweight/increase the standard errors (SEs) of such studies in aggregate data NMA, and to downweight observations from that study in IPDNMA.
I thought of seeing the issue as "how to account for uncertainty of single-imputation methods".
In my opinion, I should decrease the weight to individuals and increase the SE of mean estimates of the studies only measuring condition 1, with values depending on the correlation between Scores 1 and 2. But how would the formula be? If the correlation were 1, there would be no SE inflation and no weight decrease. But how do such quantities increase (for SE) or decrease (for weight) as the correlation moves away from 1? I see it as, for study $i$:

$SE(Score_i)=SE(Score_1i)*f_1(corr(Score_{1i}, Score_{2i}))$
and weight

$W(Score_i)=f_2(corr(Score_{1i}, Score_{2i}))$, with

$f_1(corr(Score_{1i}, Score_{2i}))=1=f_2(corr(Score_{1i}, Score_{2i}))$ for $corr(Score_{1i}, Score_{2i})=1$.
Also, I think it could make sense to give weight=$1/2$ (thus, $f_1=\sqrt{2}, f_2=1/2$ in case of $0$ correlation), but I'm not sure.

Is my reasoning correct? In case, how would these functions $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ be?